# How do I write a where query to only include 1 entity of child

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have entities

```
Blog{ blogId, name, creatorUserId }

BlogSettings{ blogId, userId, column1  }
```

Now I have a method that accepts `blogId` and `userId` and I am querying on `Blog` (not `BlogSettings`)

`Blog` contains collection of `BlogSettings`.

How should I do it?

If I write `context.Blogs.Include("BlogSettings").Where( b => b.BlogId == blogId)` that would be very inefficient since I only need that BlogSettings whose userId == userId.

`Note:` I am not querying on BlogSettings. As you can see I am querying on Blog collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var blogWithSetting = context.Blogs
    .Where(b => b.BlogId == blogId)
    .Select(b => new
    {
        Blog = b,
        BlogSetting = b.BlogSettings.FirstOrDefault(bs => bs.UserId == userId)
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (blogWithSetting != null)
{
    Blog blog = blogWithSetting.Blog;
    //
}
```

Such a projection is the only way to get the result in a single roundtrip to the database because eager loading with `Include` doesn't support any filtering or sorting on the included child collections. The `blog.BlogSettings` will be populated automatically with the single loaded `BlogSetting`, *if* you don't disable change tracking and if the relationship is not many-to-many. Otherwise you must fill the collection manually using the properties of the result object:

```
if (blogWithSetting != null)
{
    Blog blog = blogWithSetting.Blog;
    blog.BlogSettings = new List<BlogSetting>();
    blog.BlogSettings.Add(blogWithSetting.BlogSetting);
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although notionally you're querying on `Blog`, you may find it more efficient to write your query against `BlogSettings` and add `.Include("Blog")`.

Presumaby you only ever have one `BlogSettings` for a combination of UserId and BlogId; perhaps this is enforced by a unique constraint.  If that is the case, this would be really fast:

```
    var blogAndSettings = (from s in context.BlogSettings
                                            .Include("Blog")
                           where s.BlogId = blogId && s.UserId = userId
                           select s).SingleOrDefault();
```

This would require that you create a navigation property from `BlogSettings` to `Blog` called `Blog`.

Comment: Well. This is the obvious answer but as I already stated my query is written on Blogs and not BlogSettings. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This will execute a join between `Blog` and `BlogSettings` tables but just materialize the `BlogSetting` entities.

```
var settings = context.Blogs.Where( b => b.BlogId == blogId && b.CreatorUserId = userId)
                            .SelectMany(x => x. BlogSettings);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
context.Blogs.Include("BlogSettings").SingleOrDefault( b => b.BlogId == blogId);
```

Comment: This is totally wrong and inefficient. It will load all BlogSettings. Please read my question.